# I cannot extend (subclass) DataReceivedEventArgs?

Tags: c#, events, controls

I'm trying to extend DataReceivedEventArgs so that I can pass in additional data to a class that is extending Process.  Pretty much rather than just get Data from a process when hooking up to Process.OutputDataReceived, I would like to pass in a control for it to write to.

When trying to extend DataReceivedEventArgs I get errors:

```
The type 'System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs' has no constructors defined

public class DataReceivedArgsWithControl : DataReceivedEventArgs
{
    public Control ControlAdded { get; set; }
}
```

How can I add another property to this Args?  I've extended EventArgs itself because it has a constructor, but not sure how to extend this Args.

Comment: Just make your own event and EventArgs class, no need to derive.

Comment: I need a property that is provided in `DataReceivedEventArgs`: `public string Data { get; }`

Comment: Yes, that's what you'll need for your own EventArgs class when you raise your own event.  Like Steve did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you can't because the constructor is `Internal`. Perhaps a better approach would be to wrap the `DataReceivedEventArgs` inside your `EventArgs` derived class.

```
class MyDataReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
   DataReceivedEventArgs _inner;

   public MyDataReceivedEventArgs(DataReceivedEventArgs inner, object extraProperty)
   {
      _inner = inner;
      ExtraProperty = extraProperty;
   }

   public object ExtraProperty { get; private set;}
   public DataReceivedEventArgs DataArgs  
   { 
     get
     {
        return _inner;
     }
   }
}
```

Of course, this might not be suitable if you need the polymorphism with `DataReceivedEventArgs`. If you have an event handler that is expecting a `DataReceivedEventArgs` then it won't work with the wrapper class. For example:

```
public void MyHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) { ... }
```

This could only receive a `DataReceivedEventArgs` instance or an instance of a derived type, which your wrapper is not. So it depends if you need to treat your custom EventArgs class is if it were a `DataReceivedEventArgs` anywhere.

UPDATE-

If you can't change the signature of the delegate you're using from `public delegate void DataReceivedEventHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)` then you can still subscribe using a method with the signature `void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)` thanks to contravariance of delegate parameters and then check the actual type of the `EventArgs` parameter.

```
public void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var dataEventArgs = e as MyDataReceivedEventArgs;

   if(dataEventArgs != null
   {
      var extendedProperty = dataEventArgs.ExtraProperty;
      var innerArgs = dataEventArgs.DataArgs;
   }
}
```

The ideal option would be to redefine the delegate type to match your wrapper, but the above approach will work.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more with your last sentence?  I'm not sure I understand where I can get into trouble using this type of wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I think that this will be a problem then.  The process.OutputDataReceived event is expecting a DataReceivedEventHandler, which is expecting a DataReceivedEventArgs: `public delegate void DataReceivedEventHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)`.  Looks like I will have to find another way to get this type of functionality

Comment: Not necessarily. If you can't redefine the delegate then you can take advantage of delegate covariance which is not ideal in this case but will work. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I've done the following and got errors: `process.OutputDataReceived += new MyEventHandler(TestMethod)`.  The signature for TestMethod is: `MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)`.  The error states: `Cannot convert type project.MyEventHandler to System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler`. Did I forget something?

Comment: Try instead either `process.OutputDataReceived += TestMethod` or process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(TestMethod)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4275/discussion-between-steve-rowbotham-and-hans-gruber)

Comment: It looks like the process.OutputDataReceived += TestMethod worked.  Thanks!